# How many ways can six 3’s and four 2’s be arranged in a row so that 2’s are always apart?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So i know the answer is 7C4=35 but what i am wondering is why the following way to solve gives me the wrong answer.

So total ways to arranging six 3’s and four 2’s: 10!/(6!4!) = 210

I considered the ways so that the 2's are always together. I group the 2's into a single group so now we have 7 elements to arrange with six 3's that are repeating. So the ways so that 2's are always together is 7!/6! = 7

Shouldn't 210 - 7 = 203 be the ways of arranging so that 2's are always apart?

Comment: *Always apart* here means that *no* two $2$s are adjacent. For instance, the arrangment $3223332332$ is not acceptable, because the first two $2$s are adjacent.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019469/easy-counting-questionarrangement/

Comment: Do not forget that when negating a phrase which contains a "for all" remember that it changes to a "there exists."  The negation of "all twos are apart" is **not** "all twos are together", it is in fact "*there exist* some twos which are together"

Comment: I viewed that link but Im unable to leave comments due to low reputation. This question was moreso wondering why my specific reasoning didn't work but i now understand why thankyou

Answer (score 1):

No, because you only consider the anti-case where all 7 2s are bunched up together. Even if only 2 2s are together, it still is not valid..